# How can I make an arrayformula accept queries from columns that don't have any data present yet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to use array formula and a query to insert data from columns of another sheet using:

```
=arrayformula({QUERY(DS1!A2:CM,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K where K >= 0");QUERY(DS1!A2:CM,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,L,M where M >= 0")})
```

I want it to also be able to query the next column that doesn't have any data yet. But when I add:

```
;QUERY(DS1!A2:CM,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,L,M where M >= 0")
```

after the last query in the formula I get this error:

> Error In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

How can I set up the query formula to allow for blank columns that will eventually have data in them?

Is this possible?

I bet I need to take a different approach than `where M >= 0`  but every time I used `where L<>""` it errored out.

In the end I am going to be adding about 20 different queries to the array formula that all start blank until data is added.

EX. ;QUERY(DS1!A2:CM,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,L,M where M >= 0"

It is going to have in the query DS1 from A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,L,M where M...to A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,L,M where CL,CM...

Here is the link to the [spreadsheet in question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z6aAZH7BKl1pvpb9AgBrB8LZ-W_oSjE9XQAy_auBeao/edit#gid=443502671).

Sheet **DQ1** is getting its data from **DS1** , which is getting its data from **Data by Standard** .  DQ1 has to be dynamic because DS1 and Data by Standard are also dynamic and columns of data get added in those two sheets as well.

There are many Sheets used in this spreadsheet that are hidden in the example where the data is inputted.

Comment: Aren't the formulas very similar if not the same?  If not, I'm sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I removed the tag.  Thank you, I was not aware.

Comment: @pnuts thanks, I had a similar issue and I had to match the number of columns in each section of the array literal.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this entirely answers your question, but it may help point you in the right direction. First, I think pnuts is correct about array sizes. I can't make anything work when they are different sizes. I can only view your sample spreadsheet, so I am not able to do much with that. However, on sample data I set up, the below formula does let me have blank 'where' columns and fill them later. I also did not use 'is not null' since this seems to have some problems. See if you can work with this.

```
=iferror(arrayformula({QUERY(Sheet1!A2:CM7,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where K <>'' OR K >=0 OR M <>'' OR M >=0")}),"")
```